# how to charge a map in Csfml

Tags: c, file, sfml

I am making a game in **CSFML** for the purpose of a school exercise

In order to fit all the requirement I must a game who follows the rule of a finite runne suc as geometry dash. It does everything except a major feature: get a map from a file that will be like:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXE
111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

- X representing nothing (they will be a background that is displayed)
- 2 is spike
- 1 is the ground
- E is the end, it will stop the program after displaying a victory screen
  (each character will be replace by the texture who is assigned except X who represent empty space)

I had only access to  few C functions ( write, free, malloc, rand, open, read,getline)
I was thinking about just reading the file and storing it as a char*, but the thing is I don't know how to make spikes appear on the screen one by one, when they must.

Comment: You should split your problem into several parts. Design the structure for your map, load it from file, display it. What is your issue, loading from file or display ? What have you try ?

Comment: i am already able to get all the map character but my probleme is about displaying it.

Comment: Try getting as close as possible to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a size for all of your blocks.
Each blocks (X, 2, 1, E) need to have the same size.

Example (with block 64*64px)

```
void display_map(char **map)
{
    char *image = NULL;
    int size_block = 64;
    for (int i = 0; map[i] != NULL; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; map[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            switch (map[i][j]) {
                case 'X':
                    image = "nothing";
                    break;
                case '2':
                    image = "pike";
                    break;
                // ....
            }
            display_at_position(i * size_block, j * size_block, image);
        }
    }
}
```